# grib1: how to extract subregion data

Tags: grib

I have a grib1 file that contains information for the whole world and I want to extract data from box/subregion based on latitude and longitude box. Both wgrib and ecCodes/GRIB-API do not seem to have this option.  Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks in advances!

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest using cdo and operator remap for the task. Basically, you can interpolate from initial (large) grid to another (smaller) grid.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the existing CDO answer the full command is

```
cdo sellonlatbox,lon1,lon2,lat1,lat2 inputfile.grb mynewbox.grb
```

Note, no spaces between the lon and lat specifications (a common error).

For further details, [you can check out my guide on this topic here](https://youtu.be/ewii1p1kChw)